# Is there a way to return IPFS image files in ascending order

Tags: node.js, sorting, ipfs

I'm trying to return all the images stored in IPFS but the order is not sorted and does not return how they are listed in IPFS Desktop

A screenshot of IPFS desktop images in ascending order
[image: Images stored in IPFS Desktop]

The code configured to get the images from IPFS

```
import fs from 'fs';

import { create, urlSource } from 'ipfs'

const cid = 'QmP9Sh6kU2qjh8mHuu3rmuEECpRFrZtjaxMHQR7sKgRmL3'

const main = async () => {

    const ipfs = await create();

    const list = ipfs.ls(cid);

    for await (const item of list) {

        console.log(item)

    }

}

main()
```

Returns the IPFS image objects but not in ascending order
[image]

Comment: Store every item in a array and sort the array?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find a solution for returning the images in order from IPFS but was able to create a key/value pair mapping between the image name which returned an integer and the image file path. This method proved to work for my situation.

```
// Declares the map
  const map = new Map();

  // Iterates through the images
    for await (const item of list) {
      
    // Pushes the IPFS image path to the array for storage
    imagePath.push(item.path);

    // Pushes the IPFS image name to the array for storage
    imageName.push(item.name);

    // Creates the key/value pair for the IPFS images
    map.set(parseInt(item.name), item.path);
        
    }
```